# Swift animatewithDuration() instantly completes

Tags: swift3, alpha, animatewithduration

So, I have this code:

```
UIView.animate(withDuration: 10.0, delay: 0, options: .curveLinear , animations: { 
            self.gameLabel.alpha = 0
}, completion: nil)
```

The problem is when this code is called it instantly goes to a 0 alpha and doesn't slowly transition. What am I doing wrong?

Here is some more context for the the code:

```
var gameLabel = SKLabelNode()

override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
    gameLabel.fontColor = UIColor.white
    gameLabel.fontSize = 85
    gameLabel.setScale(0.40)
    gameLabel.text = "this is a game"
    gameLabel.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    gameLabel.zPosition = 0
    gameLabel.alpha = 1

    addChild(gameLabel)   
}

func touchDown(atPoint pos : CGPoint) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 2, animations: {
            self.gameLabel.alpha = 0
    })
}
```

Comment: Your animation code looks correct. Can you post additional context? There might be some other factor causing the issue.

Comment: it's in the method taps begin or whatever, the one which is called when you tap the screen

Answer (score 1):

So, i solved my problem by running.

`self.gameLabel.run(SKAction.fadeOut(withDuration: 10))`

Comment: I was gonna say. You normally can't use UIView.animation to animate SKNodes and stuff. Stick to SKActions all the time. :D